# Defining variables and arrays using the else statement - Python

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to apply a quality control filter to a large dataset from a netCDF file. Within the netCDF there is a dimension called nstorms where there are lat, lon, date, and other variables associated with each nstorm value (where nstorms ranges from 0 to 230348). In order to apply the quality control I'm currently using a for loop with an if and else statement:

```
for i in range(len(lowerBound)):
  if min37[i] >= lowerBound[i] and min37[i] < upperBound[i]:
    nstorms_bad = i
    print nstorms_bad
  else:
    nstorms_good =  #everything else - all the other 'i' values
    print nstorms_good
    #Put values for nstorms_good into an array
```

lowerBound is the same size as nstorms and since both nstorms and lowerBound start at zero the value returned for `nstorms_bad = i` matches the bad data in the netCDF (i.e. the first few values returned for nstorms_bad are 306, 408, 486 and these values match the erroneous data associated with nstorms 306, 408 and 486 in the netCDF file).

The problem I am having is that I need the good nstorms values and I need to put them into an array so that I can go back into the netCDF file and associate each value of nstorms_good with its respective variable data (lat, lon, time, etc...). If I set `nstorms_good = i` then I just get a list of all the `i` values without any of the quality control applied? What would be the best way to define `nstorms_good` so that it contains all of the `i` values except for the bad ones (since using `i` matches up with the actual nstorms) and how do I put all of those values into an array? Would it be easier to just set `nstorms_bad` as an array and then create a new array for `nstorms_good` containing the numbers 0 to 230348 and then compare the two arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to iterate later over all `nstorms_good`. Therefore any container would do: `list`, `dict` or even `set`.

Using `dict` would allow you to store some additional data about each `nstorms_good`, but since you really only need indices, I'd go with list:

```
nstorms_good = []
for i in range(len(lowerBound)):
  if min37[i] >= lowerBound[i] and min37[i] < upperBound[i]:
    ...
  else:
    nstorms_good.append( i )

# process
for nstorm in nstorms_good:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to want is two lists one of which has all the indices associated with the bad storms in your storms data list and one with the good_storms. This would be like

```
god = []
bad = []
for i in range(len(lowerBound):
  if min37[i] >= lowerBound[i] and min37[i] < upperBound:
    bad.append(i)
  else:
    good.append(i)
```

You can now loop over the two lists and get the appropriate references.

Comment: Thanks! This definitely helped a lot!